# Sending messages from main process to renderer in Electron in 2022

Tags: electron, ipc

In my App I have two windows: `mainWindow` and `actionWindow`. **On my mainWindow I use the `ipcRenderer.on` listener to receive as message from the main process when the actionWindow is closed. The message however doesn't come through.**

The `mainWindow` is used to control actions that take place on the `actionWindow` (e.g. navigate to an URL, remotely close the window, ...). I want to give the user the power to move and close the `actionWindow` manually as well, which is why its title bar is visible and usable.

I expose `ipcRenderer.invoke` for two-way communication and `ipcRenderer.on` to the mainWindow's renderer via contextBridge in a preload file.

This is what the code looks like (based on [vite-electron-builder template](https://github.com/cawa-93/vite-electron-builder))

**main process**

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  show: false, // Use 'ready-to-show' event to show window
  webPreferences: {
    nativeWindowOpen: true,
    webviewTag: false,
    preload: join(__dirname, "../../preload/dist/index.cjs"),
  },
});
const actionWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  // some props
})
actionWindow.on("close", () => {
  console.log("window closed")
  mainWindow.webContents.send("closed", { message: "window closed" });
});
```

**preload**

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("ipcRenderer", {
  invoke: ipcRenderer.invoke,
  on: ipcRenderer.on,
});
```

**renderer (mainWindow)**

```js
window.ipcRenderer.on("closed", () => {
  console.log("message received")
  // do something
  });
```

I know for a fact that

- mainWindow has access to the exposed listeners, since `invoke` works and the actions it fires on the main process are executed on the actionWindow as supposed + the response also comes back to the renderer.
- the `close` listener on the actionWindow works since I can see the log `window closed` in my console
- `message received` doesn't appear in my dev tools console

To me this means that either

- `mainWindow.webContents.send` doesn't work -> the message is never sent
- `window.ipcRenderer.on` doesn't work -> the message never reaches its destination

So either my code is buggy or Electron has recently put some restrictions on one of these methods which I'm not aware of.

Any ideas?
If there is a smarter way to do this than IPC I'm also open to that.

Answer (score 4):

Ok after hours of searching, trying and suffering I (almost accidentaly) found a solution to my problem. It really seems to be the case that electron simply doesn't do anything anymore when you call the `on` method from your renderer.
Studying the [docs about contextBridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge) again I saw that the way I exposed `invoke` and `on` to the renderer, was considered bad code. The safer way to do this is expose a function for EVERY ipc channel you want to use. In my case using TypeScript it looks like this:

**preload**

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("ipcRenderer", {
  invokeOpen: async (optionsString: string) => {
    await ipcRenderer.invoke("open", optionsString);
  },
  onClose: (callback: () => void) => {
    ipcRenderer.on("closed", callback);
  },
  removeOnClose: (callback: () => void) => {
    ipcRenderer.removeListener("closed", callback);
  },
});
```

**renderer(mainWindow)**

```js
window.ipcRenderer.onClose(() => {
  // do sth
});
window.ipcRenderer.invokeOpen(JSON.stringify(someData)).then(() => {
  // do sth when response came back
});
```

**NOTE**: To prevent memory leaks by creating listeners on every render of the mainWindow you also have to use a cleanup function which is provided with `removeOnClose` (see preload). How to use this function differs depending on the frontend framework. Using React it looks like this:

```js
const doSth= () => {
    console.log("doing something")
    ...
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.ipcRenderer.onClose(doSth);
    return () => {
      window.ipcRenderer.removeOnClose(doSth);
    };
  }, []);
```

**Not only is this a safer solution, it actually suddenly works :O**
Using the cleanup function we also take care of leaks.